# SQL statement based on $curr_time->format('Y-m-d H:i')

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why this code...

```
$curr_time = new DateTime();
$query_inprocess = "UPDATE `MyTable` 
                    SET inprocess=1 
                    WHERE startTime <= '" .$curr_time->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "'";
```

...results in incorrect SQL query, in which the statement after `<` is ignored?

```
UPDATE `MyTable` SET inprocess=1 WHERE startTime <
```

Comment: Use parameterised queries and avoid having to format data types yourself.

Comment: Does the '=' from '<= ...' get ignored too?

Comment: What is exactly the error message you are getting?

Comment: "UPDATE \`MyTable\` SET inprocess=1 WHERE startTime <" -- Is that the output when you `echo $query_inprocess;` or is it part of a MySQL error message? It looks like the problem is somewhere else in your code that isn't shown here.

Comment: You defined `$curr_time`. Don't you have to set a value for it?

Comment: @ypercube: It should default to the current time.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wu4EUg

Answer (score 1):

Find the below one :

```
"UPDATE `MyTable` SET inprocess=1 WHERE startTime <= now()"
```

It may help you to get the exact result which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$curr_time = new DateTime();
$query_inprocess = "UPDATE `MyTable` 
                    SET inprocess=1 
                    WHERE startTime <='" .$curr_time->format('Y-m-d H:i'). "'";//OR use date('Y-m-d H:i') instead of $curr_time->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```

Comment: Why would the space make a difference?

Comment: @YouKuper: Have you checked your `error_reporting` setting in your php.ini file? Perhaps the script is generating an error that you're not seeing.